# T-SQL stored procedure return a void type value and cannot use the value for another select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures, return-value

I have a return value from stored procedure. But when I use the value for another `select`, it doesn't give me anything. I can only change my code part which I explained below but I cannot change any existing table and any existing stored procedure. So, please look my code and give me some advice what I am missing or what I do wrong. I feel it's maybe `type` issue or I am not sure. The stored procedure does not use output, just selects one id from table.

Thank you!

My code:

```
declare @id int

exec @id = stored_proc
print (@id) -- it prints 21 which means stored procedure is returning a value

select type_name(@id) -- I was just curious to see the type and it shows 'void type'

select * 
from table
where id = @id -- it doesn't return anything 

set @id = 21

select type_name(@id) -- I was again curious to see type and here it shows 'NULL'

select * 
from table
where id = @id -- it returns the row with an id of 21
```

Comment: I actually used CAST and Convert both for @id to convert it to INT. But none of them worked.

Comment: Just an experiment - if you create another variable, let's say `@temp int` and then do `select @temp = @id`, what does `select @temp` return?

Comment: @j.kaspar, thanks for comment, it returns 0

Comment: I think my stored procedure is returning table. I just used this way and it returns 21. 

Declare @T Table ([id] int)

 Insert @T exec stored_proc

 select * from @T